# Fiz um leitor de pdf em python com um contador pra ler página a página desse pdf mas estou errando em algo e meu "leitor" só lê a ultima página:

Tags: python, pycharm

```py
# o contador começa em -1 pq o para ler a primeira página tenho que começar do indice 0
    contador = -1 


def acessarPDF( c = contador):

    import PyPDF2

    arq = r"C:\Users\Neto\Desktop\Springer Ebooks.pdf"

    lerPdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(arq)


    pagina = lerPdf.getPage(c) 

    conteudo = pagina.extractText()

    return conteudo


while contador < 21:

    contador += 1

    acessarPDF()

pdf = acessarPDF()

print(pdf)
```

Comment: Você não deveria passar a variável `contador` para a função `acesaPDF`?

Comment: o erro esta nessa forma de contar, veja que esta invocando pagina -1, que é o final do array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Veja se dá certo assim:**

```
    import PyPDF2
    contador = 0


    def acessarPDF(c):
        arq = r"C:\Users\Neto\Desktop\Springer Ebooks.pdf"
        lerPdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(arq)
        pagina = lerPdf.getPage(c)
        conteudo = pagina.extractText()
        return conteudo


    while contador <= 21:
        """
        Troquei a posição da incrementação do contador,
        para que ele possa começar com zero.
        """

        print(acessarPDF(contador)) # Aqui vai printar e executar a função ao mesmo tempo.
        contador += 1
```

Comment: Valeu, cara. tmj!